# NoClassDefFoundError even when libs are in the PATH and CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classpath

The required jars (commons-codec and jsoup jars) is in both PATH and CLASSPATH but still getting the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Can someone please help ?

```
    $ echo $PATH    
    /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/aks/bin:/home/aks/f_group/lib/commons-codec-1.8.jar:/home/aks/f_group/lib/jsoup-1.9.2.jar

    $ echo $CLASSPATH
    /home/aks/focus_group/lib/commons-codec-1.8.jar:/home/aks/focus_group/lib/jsoup-1.9.2.jar


    $ java -cp ~/f_group/ExtractConfPages.jar com.ak.ExtractConfPages 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
    at com.ak.ExtractConfPages.main(ExtractConfPages.java:34)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more

    $ java -jar ~/f_group/ExtractConfPages.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
    at com.ak.ExtractConfPages.main(ExtractConfPages.java:34)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep `ExtractConfPages.jar` file and required jars (commons-codec and jsoup jars)
 in  the same directory(say in  ~/f_group/).
then run

```
java -cp ~/f_group/ExtractConfPages.jar com.ak.ExtractConfPages
```

Answer (score 0):

Works when i include all the jars in the classpath

java -classpath commons-codec-1.8.jar;jsoup-1.9.2.jar;ExtractConfluencePages.jar com.ak.ExtractConfluencePages